# Retrieve DOM element by id in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have a `<div>` in `home.html` as shown below. I have to retrieve this element by the ID which is `myDiv` and later pass it as a reference to a JS method.  I tried it using `@ViewChild` and it was working in `Ionic 2 beta 11`. After upgrading Ionic to the latest `rc` release, it has stopped working.

Here is my `home.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div id="myDiv" #myDiv></div>
<ion-content>
```

Here is my `home.ts`:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    @ViewChild('myDiv') defaultContent: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // console.log("ngView");
        var myDiv: HTMLDivElement = this.defaultContent.nativeElement;
    }

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

}
```

This is my Ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.8.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try start using more angular2 and typescript :)

```
public myDiv:string = '';


ngAfterViewInit() {
    // console.log("ngView");
    this.myDiv = this.defaultContent.nativeElement;
}
```

Then in your html

```
<div padding [innerHTML]="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointers. Appreciate it. We'll be trying the recommendations and will be writing to you soon.